# Fourier series without Fourier analysis techniques

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

It is known that one can sometimes derive certain Fourier series without alluding to the methods of Fourier analysis. It is often done using complex analysis. There is a way of deriving the formula
$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin(kz)}{k} = \frac{\pi - z}{2}$$
using complex analysis for some $z$. In other words, it can be shown that $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sin(kz)/k$ converges to $(\pi - z)/2$ for some $z$. My question is: How can we show that the formula above holds for $z \in (0, 2\pi)$ without using Fourier analysis?

**Edit**:

Using blue's suggestion I concocted the following proof.

Let $\log z$ be the principal value of the logarithm (with the branch cut along the negative real axis). Recall that $e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = 2i\sin z$ and $\text{Arg}(z) = \text{Arg}(z^*)$. Furthermore, we have
\begin{align*}
\log(1 - e^{iz}) &= -\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{e^{ikz}}{k} \\
&= \log|1 - e^{iz}| + i\theta \\
&= \log\left|2\sin\frac{z}{2}\right| + i\theta,
\end{align*}
where $\theta = \text{Arg}(1 - e^{iz})$. Now, write $1 - e^{iz} = 1 - \cos z - i\sin z$ and let $z \in (0, \pi)$. Then
$$\tan \theta = \frac{\sin z}{1 - \cos z} = \frac{\cos(z/2)}{\sin(z/2)} = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{z}{2}\right).$$
Hence, $\theta = \pi/2 - z/2$. Moreover, since $z \in (0, \pi)$, we have $\theta \in (0, \pi/2)$.
Using Euler's formula $e^{iz} = \cos z + i \sin z$ and the fact that the sine function is odd, we see that equating the imaginary parts gives
$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin kz}{k} = \frac{\pi - z}{2}, \quad z \in (-\pi, 0) \cup (0, \pi).$$
Lastly, observe that $(-\pi, 0) \cup (0, \pi)$ can be replaced by $(0, 2\pi)$ due to the periodicity of the sine function.

Comment: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/837891/85343) is closely related to your question and it is easily evaluated by means of Abel-Plana Formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sense of sines with complex arguments, you need to decompose them into complex exponentials. After that notice you're working with two series, each a Taylor expansion of the natural logarithm function (written appropriately). Proceed from there.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a proof using your suggestion. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Is there a shorter way?

Comment: @glebovg Yes that is what I meant. Dunno if it can be shortened, but it's the thing that immediately came to mind when you asked for non-Fourier arguments.