# Fourier series using summation methods

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, divergent-series

My question is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849901/fourier-series-without-fourier-analysis-techniques) one. There are ways of deriving the formulae like
$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin(kz)}{k} = \frac{\pi - z}{2}$$
using summation methods. My question is: How can we argue, without invoking Fourier analysis and preferably using only summation methods, that the formula above holds specifically for $z \in (0, 2\pi)$?

Comment: It's [solved here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/837891/85343) by using Abel-Plana Formula.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: I just pointed out something that was somehow closed to your question. Those type of question are always interesting. Thanks.