# Convergence test of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\cos(n)}{n\sqrt{n}})$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I can't figure out where I'm wrong, I just want to show that the series definitely converges.
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\cos(n)}{n\sqrt{n}})$
so I started by checking the absolute value.
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{|\cos(n)|}{n\sqrt{n}})$ and  $0\leq|\cos(n)|\leq1$
$\frac{|\cos(n)|}{n\sqrt{n}}\leq 
\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}$
Therefore, the comparison test can be used.
and
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}})$
is a convergent series, and therefore also the original series

Comment: This is how I would do it, why do you think you're wrong?

Comment: why do you think that you are wrong ?

Comment: Because I answered this answer in the test and got 0 points, it seems perfectly fine to me too

Comment: @complex_stock Well then you need to consult your professor, because you are completely correct.

Comment: @K.defaoitr Thanks for checking, I will

Comment: For an alternative, this converges by Dirchelet's test such as in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227574/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinnn?rq=1), Dirchelet's test just being the more generic form of the "alternating series" test.  That being said, I do think your answer is more common and elementary.

Comment: It may depend exactly what you have as the Comparison Test. I would have started like you, and said that by [my version of] the Comparison Test that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{\cos(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}|$ is convergent, and then, since absolute convergence implies convergence got that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{\cos(n)}{n\sqrt{n}})$ converges. But nul points seems harsh.